# Python-Django: Create, save, load to do list

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can save an item to a to-do list and then load the list. I'm using a sqlite3 database on a localhost. I have an input box and a save button to do the job, but can't figure out how I can make it work in Python and Django. Here is my code so far. I'm mostly stuck in the views.py code.

create.html:

```
{% extends "todo/base.html" %}

{% block title %} Anna's To-Do List {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h2>Create Your To-Do List</h2>

<form action="{% url 'todo:create' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input name="todo_item" id="todo_text" maxlength="150" placeholder="Enter a to-do item" />
    <input type="submit" id="save" value="Save">
</form>

<table id="todo_table">
    {% for todo in todo.item_set.all %}
        <tr><td>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ todo.todo_text }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<ul>
    <li><a href="{% url 'todo:index' %}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'todo:about' %}">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'todo:create' %}">Create To-Do List</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'todo:load' %}">Load To-Do List</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'todo:links' %}">Other To-Do List Links</a></li>
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect

from todo.models import todo
from todo.models import Item
from todo.forms import TodoForm

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = todo
    template_name = 'todo/index.html'

class AboutView(generic.ListView):
    model = todo
    template_name = 'todo/about.html'

class CreateView(generic.ListView):
    model = todo
    template_name = 'todo/create.html'

def addItem(self):
    t = Todo()
    t.text = request.POST.get('todo_text', '')
    t.save()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TodoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    else:
        return render(request, 'todo/create.html', {'form': form})

class LoadView(generic.ListView):
    model = todo
    template_name = 'todo/load.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Todo.objects.all().order_by('-created')

class LinksView(generic.ListView):
    model = todo
    template_name = 'todo/links.html'
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Edit:

As requested, urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

from todo import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    url(r'^about/$', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),

    url(r'^create/$', views.CreateView.as_view(), name='create'),

    url(r'^load/$', views.LoadView.as_view(), name='load'),

    url(r'^links/$', views.LinksView.as_view(), name='links'),
)
```

Edit:

Upon clicking 'Save', my page redirects to the same URL but the page is now blank. Not sure what's causing that. I do know that it doesn't save, load, or redirect properly.

Edit - Create To-Do List view:
[image: Create To-Do List view]

Comment: Your form needs to post to a url. Did you omit that on purpose?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I'm not sure how to code the buttons into Python or have the form add the item to the DB and then show up under the input box. Also, I want to save the whole list and load it later on another page

Comment: @Ben, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you clarify please?

Comment: You should check out the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/ they have some great examples

Comment: @Ben I've been reading through that but I'm confused as to how I can alter the code to fit my idea of a very simple to-do list

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I read that you're good in python and django, could you help please?

Comment: @annabananana7: what are you stuck with now? are you getting any error?

Comment: @brainstorm I'm not getting an error, but it's not saving, loading, or redirecting properly =\

Comment: one this I notice, is you don't have namespace in urls.py but you have it in your "action". change it to `create` from `todo:create`. Also when you click on `create-todo-list`, does it display the create form

Comment: I see more mistakes..Do you have this code in github?

Comment: @brainstorm removing `todo:` from all the urls gave me an error. I went through the django tutorial and they had the `todo:` when using namespaces. I added the Create To-Do List view to my question. I don't have it on github

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58388/discussion-between-brain-storm-and-annabananana7).